# Excel Exporting Multiple Data Sets to a Single Spreadsheet File

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to output multiple small data frames to an Excel file. The data frames are residuals and predicted from mgcv models run from a loop. Each is a separate small data set that I am trying to output to a separate worksheet in the same Excel spreadsheet file.

The relevant line of code that is causing the error is from what I can tell this line of code

```
write.xlsx(resid_pred, parfilename,  sheetName=parsheetname, append = TRUE)**
```

where `resid_pred` is the residuals predicted data frame, `parfilename` is the file name and path and
`parsheetname` is the sheet name.

The error message is

```
Error in save Workbook(wb, file = file, overwrite = overwrite) :   File already exists!
```

Which makes no sense since the file would HAVE to exist if I am appending to it. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly the following code will work:

```
write.xlsx2(resid_pred, file=parfilename, sheetName= parsheetname, col.names = 
TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, append = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE)
```

The only difference is it is write.**xlsx2** not just xlsx.